# Using java to query counter-strike 1.6 server info

Tags: java, udp

guys I am trying to write a simple java program to query counter-strike 1.6 server:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class Test {

    private static DatagramSocket ds;

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ds = new DatagramSocket(27024);
            byte[] data;
            // TSource Engine Query
            char peer0_0[] = { 
                0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 
                0x54, 0x53, 0x6f, 0x75,
                0x72, 0x63, 0x65, 0x20, 
                0x45, 0x6e, 0x67, 0x69, 
                0x6e, 0x65, 0x20, 0x51, 
                0x75, 0x65, 0x72, 0x79, 0x00 
            };
            data = new String(peer0_0).getBytes();

            System.out.println("send:" + new String(data));

            DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(data, 0, data.length, InetAddress.getByName("219.133.59.20"), 27021);
            ds.send(dp);
            byte[] rec = new byte[1024];
            DatagramPacket dp2 = new DatagramPacket(rec, 1024);
            ds.receive(dp2);

            System.out.println("revice:" + new String(rec));

            ds.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if(ds != null) ds.close();
        }
    }

}
```

after sending query msg, it did not receive any thing, and the program will not exit.
I am sure there is a server on 219.133.59.20:27021
what's wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran your code with no issues. The output is as follows:

```
send:ÿÿÿÿTSource Engine Query
revice:ÿÿÿÿm127.0.0.1:27021CoVerTæˆ˜é˜Ÿæ·±åœ³6å?·ç–¯å?‹è®°æœ?åŠ¡å™¨ã€?KPã€‘
```

I suspect you're having issues with your firewall/router. From http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/index.html:

> **Note:**  Many firewalls and routers are configured not to allow UDP
>   packets. If you have trouble connecting to a service outside your
>   firewall, or if clients have trouble connecting to your service, ask
>   your system administrator if UDP is permitted.

Comment: Can you see server response ?

Comment: Yes, I see the server response, though it seems to mostly be binary.  I added it to my answer description.  Hope that helps!

Comment: it seems that is a encoding problem,

Comment: Hey @MansoorSiddiqui can we have a little conversation please?